# converting date string (Y-m-d) into "Mar 2nd" php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am retireiving date strings in the form Y-m-d from a mySQL table (ex. 2010-12-03) using an array $row[dt];

```
echo $row["dt"]; // in a while loop
```

I would like output that stored string as  "Mar 2nd"

I have tried `strtotime()` and `date( "m d", $row['dt'] )` but they don't work.. the latter, for instance, just outputs "Dec 31"

can this be done?  thanks

Comment: Have you tried `echo date("m d", strtotime($row['dt']));`

Comment: echo date("M jS", strtotime($row['dt']));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for. The reason for the `j` instead of the `d` is because the poster asked for *Mar 2nd*. Using `d` would output *Mar 02nd*.

```
echo date("M jS", strtotime($row['dt']));
```

Edit: M instead of m.

Comment: m would display the numerical representation of month. Try M instead of m

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PHP doesn't have built-in support for ordinal suffices, so you'd have to do it manually.

Include the following function in your code:

```
function suffix($number) {
    $last = substr($number, -1, 1);
    switch($last) {
        case "1": return "st";
        case "2": return "nd";
        case "3": return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
```

...then your PHP would be:

```
echo date( "m d", $row['dt'] ) . suffix( date( "d", $row['dt'] ) );
```

Comment: Actually, the date function *does* support ordinal suffices: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. It's `S`, so your date string should be `"M dS"`.

Comment: I don't think date will convert the format YYYY-MM-DD into a valid timestamp?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
Also, use `j` instead of `d`. Using `d` would give you 01st, which looks odd.

Comment: echo date("M jS", strtotime($row['dt']));

Answer (score 0):

You can convert like this,

```
echo date("M jS", strtotime($row['dt']));
```

Here, you can get all PHP date & time formats..

**[PHP DATE & TIME FORMATS](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ss/php_functions_3.htm)**